# Magento 1.9: How to show image on admin form Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, edit

In my `Magento 1.9` I have created a `module` and there from `Front-end` to end customer fill form with image.

At admin panel I have all form detail but don't know how to display image.
Image will be `only display` not `editable`.

Please anybody can suggest me.
Thank you

Comment: any one have idea about it ?

Comment: Where do you store the uploaded images? Fo you store the image's name in your db?

Comment: @yiotgos image storing in media directory.  Please suggest me what is syntax to display image on admin .

Comment: please any can reply ? thank you

Comment: There is really no info to go through. 1. What is your module doing? Do you store the uploading info in a db table? 2. Where do you want to display he image?

Displaying the image in the backend is as simple as passing the images url on an <img> source tag. But you have to have the URL some how

Comment: @yiotgos, my module is display form in frontend and user fill it. Then at admin panel we have list of all forms which submitted by users. and At admin panel have grid to manage all forms and by click on view link admin can view all details of particular form. want to display image(which user selected) also. Image name is stored in database with all other information.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved.
 On edit/update form($fieldset->addField), we can not display image, So i
 showed link and on click of link image showed. Thank you